# Update Hang-Fire default worker count from 20 to a custom number in ABP Framework

Tags: hangfire, abp

I would like to update the concurrent background job count from the default 20 to 10. Where can I mention this configuration ? There is this [link](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/throttling.html) which gives some information. But how do I configure this in ABP framework ?

I have tried below config but I still get 20 parallel jobs

```
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    var configuration = context.Services.GetConfiguration();

    Configure<AbpAutoMapperOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AddMaps<DemoApplicationModule>();
    });

    ConfigureHangfire(context, configuration);
}
private void ConfigureHangfire(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    context.Services.AddHangfire(config =>
    {
        config.UseSqlServerStorage(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
        
    });
    context.Services.Configure<BackgroundJobServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.WorkerCount = 10;
        options.SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    });
    context.Services.AddTransient<IBackgroundServiceManagement,BackgroundServiceManagement>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change the degree of parallelism, you are probably looking for this, [Configuring Degree of Parallelism](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html) and changing the WorkerCount.

This allows you to change the default queue processing count from defaults but remember that the size should not be larger than number of processors * 5 (as mentioned in the documentation)

Update: @Jerry
Not sure if there is a fix for this in abp but there is a post that talks about how one fixed the issue by using the following singleton

```
context.Services.AddSingleton(provider => new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
    WorkerCount = 10
});
```

Taken from [this post](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/5378)